# Pass Javascript $_GET variables to CodeIgniter Model via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps, codeigniter

Good Morning, Im using the Google Maps V3 to implement a project.

In my view, an infowindow opens that the user input data. I want to save that data to my database.

My addMarker model function should grab the entered data and save it to my database.
Currently, the infoWindow opens and I can enter information. But that data isn't sent to the 
addMarker function in my model.

```
function saveData() {


      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var item = escape(document.getElementById("item").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("weapon").value;
      //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
     var url= "http://localhost:8888/index.php/site_model/addMarker?name="+ name
    +"&item="+item+"&weapon="+weapon;

 downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.responseText <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
        }

else
    {alert('NOT done');
    alert('TEST');
    }
      });

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
```

addMarker Model function in Site_model

```
function addMarker()
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' =>$this->input->post('name'),
            'item' =>$this->input->post('item'),
            'lat' =>$this->input->post('lat'),
            'lng' =>$this->input->post('lng'),
            'weapon' =>$this->input->post('weapon'),
            'injured' =>$this->input->post('injured')
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('data', $data);
        return $insert;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use a "$_GET" querystring in the uri, but trying to access the info via Codeigniter "$_POST" access.

Make sure you have enabled querystrings in your application/config.php

which is usually line 151 in config.php

Change:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

To:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

This will enable you to use querystrings to grab "$_GET" information from the url.

Also, Make sure in your processing function in "site_model" you use

```
$this->input->get('name');
```

instead of

```
$this->input->post('name');
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for the assistance, I adjusted to enable query strings and changed to GET.

I'm getting the same Dev. Tools Chrome error:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) --addMarker"

Comment: ok, well, to trouble shoot just try and hit "http://localhost:8888/robmenot/index.php/site_model/addMarker" comment out your addMarker logic and just echo "This URL works".  If it doesn't we know better where to start troubleshooting this issue.  Sounds like your URL just simply isn't connecting, on top of mis-using GET querystring data as POST.

Comment: Also, it strikes me as strange that you are accessing a model via url, I believe you might just simply need to review codeigniter documentation on the proper usage of the MVC paradigm.  Generally you would submit this information to a Controller, that would then perform any logic or processing, and then send it on to the model to be inserted/updated in the database.

Comment: Hey Jon, I simply switched the logic operation from the Model to the Controller and it now works.
Thanks much